# How to present a Tab Bar Controller from a UI View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

This is the situation...

I have UIViewController, I want to programatically, without any buttons, to go to my Tab Bar Controller or to one of my Table View Controllers.

This is what I did so far:

**UIViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"appLaunched" sender:self];}];
}
```

This does not work, I made a segue and gave it an id, but the issue remains, my app when launches just shows a white screen and the transition is never made. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self pushIt];
}

- (void)pushIt
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"appLaunched"] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you.. it's not doing it, the destination is a Tab Bar Controller, i also tried in a Table View Controller but nothing. It does not give an error, it just stays black.